# What does MPNS response with status code 200 and notification status 'Dropped' mean?

Tags: windows-phone, mpns

For some push messages sent using MPNS I am getting a response with the following values:

- statusCode = 200
- notificationStatus = Dropped
- deviceConnectionStatus = Connected
- subscriptionStatus = Active

Looking at the only documentation I found it seems the meaning of this particular combination is not explained:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff941100(v=vs.105).aspx

What I want to know is if I should treat this as an error and if so, should I retry later or just give up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if we cannot find a specific documentation to check the particular combination you provide, we can still analyze it based on our common experience:

- `200 OK` means your request has been received successfully
- `Dropped` means the MPNS has not received your request normally
- `Connected` refers to your device status when the request is sent
- The last header returns if the channel is still valid(`Active`) or not(`Expired`)

Thus, I think you can retry later since your channel is still valid.